# Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, youtube-api, google-api-client

I'm using "Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C" for uploading videos to youtube and my app always crashes since yesterday at GTLService class.

After video was uploaded (and appears at youtube), GTL call the
`- (void)parseObjectFromDataOfFetcher:(GTMHTTPFetcher *)fetcher` method at GTLService.m

And crashes at 1087 line of code: 
`NSString *contentType = [responseHeaders objectForKey:@"Content-Type"];`
coz responseHeaders have bad data or its already released.

[image]

Anybody have same issue or ideas what's happening?

Comment: your `responseHeader` is released before you use it.. check it where it actually get released. Try retaining it till it is in use